# Application not running on 64 bit machine

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I am woking on Windows Server 2008 r2. I have installed 32-bit MS SQL Server Express Edition, and the 32-bit JDK and JRE. After I create the DSN to connect to the database (using 32 bit ODBC) and run my JAP application, the following error is displayed: Architecture mismatch between DSN and application.

Answer (score 1):

> To manage a data source that connects
>   to a 32-bit driver under 64-bit
>   platform, use
>   c:\windows\sysWOW64\odbcad32.exe. To
>   manage a data source that connects to
>   a 64-bit driver, use
>   c:\windows\system32\odbcad32.ex

The page then goes on to say:

> To resolve this error, use the 32-bit
>   odbcad32.exe to configure or remove
>   the DSN.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms712362(VS.85).aspx

**This has never happened to me, just found this with a quick Google Search.**